# fprintf and fwrite (written bytes to fp)

Tags: c, printf, fwrite

I have question about fprintf and fwrite. 
How many bytes are written when this code runs (assuming fp has been correctly set up).

```
int i = 10000;

fprintf(fp,"%d",i);

fwrite(fp,sizeof(int),1,&i);
```

When I checked then 5 bytes and 9 bytes respectively. Maybe I am wrong.  I thought it is 4 bytes since int. Can someone explain please??? Thanks.

Comment: sizeof(int) can be 4 or 8 depending on platform. Regarding the 9th byte ... is this DOS/Windows and the file was opened without `b` modifier then the final byte may be a `^Z` end-of-file marker? Is that last bytes value `0x1A`?

Comment: The `printf()` writes 5 bytes because `"10000"` is 5 characters.  The `fwrite()` writes 4 bytes (for a total file size of 9 bytes) because `sizeof(int) == 4` on your platform.  So, if the output file is 9 bytes long at the end of the program and those are the only relevant output operations to the file, then it is WAI (working as intended), which may or may not be WAE (working as expected) for you, but is WAE for me -- my expectations may not be the same as yours, IOW.

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf` writes the string `10000` (5 bytes) to the file, while `fwrite` writes binary representation of `10000` (`sizeof(int)` bytes) to the file.

Answer (score 1):

How are you checking the number of bytes written? sizeof(int) depends on platform.

Given below is the function signature for fwrite.

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

fwrite writes an array of count elements, each one with a size of size bytes, from the block of memory pointed by ptr to stream. The return value gives the actual number of bytes written. Mostly it is going to be size * count.

Similarly fprintf returns the number of characters written/printed.

Answer (score 1):

`fprintf(fp,"%d",i);` writes 5 bytes. it writes 10000 as string, 5 chars